# Using 16V battery indicator on a 420V supply

Tags: led, analog, indicator

Does anyone have an idea how can I use a 16V indicator on 420V supply?

I have tried using voltage divider like this but failed. When I measure VR2 without the battery indicator the voltage is ~16V.  After I connect my indicator the voltage drops to 3,4V. Is it because of the low impedance in the battery indicator circuit?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Depends, how much current or power does it consume?

Comment: _”Is it because low impedance in battery indicator circuit?”_ Yes. Please find out how much it consumes at its rated voltage and that can be taken into account for your divider.

Comment: Get a voltage indicator for the required voltage range, if you don't want to kill yourself, connecting a 16V instrument to 400V is asking for hazard.

Comment: A voltage divider is unregulated and sensitive to the load. You need to know what you are doing before playing around with high voltages.

Comment: The voltage divider would only work properly if **no current** is drawn from it. Your voltage meter obviously does take a current. That will influence the voltage divider. *supply is only from capacitor, i think its safe enough* Obviously you've never been shocked by a 400 V capacitor before. After that happens you will not be saying that this is "safe enough".

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted links showing technical information for each of the hardware devices. A schematic of the indicator would be an unbelievable help.

Comment: Right, that’s certainly more complicated. Best case would be to have a small DC/DC to step down the supply voltage to your circuit and just a divider to scale the voltage for the sensing. Is this a one-off or mass production?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a tricky design. The input feeds a low dropout regulator that is used as a reference but it is limited to a maximum of 5 - 6 volts depending on which manufacturer's data sheet is referenced. It would not survive a 16V battery as drawn, the regulator stated would fry. It shows 4 op amps driving 4 LEDs. Because of the way the input is configured it powers the Op amps and is divided down to 4 reference points. The op amps are being used as comparators, this OK and it will give a positive output with some current capability where a typical low cost comparator has an open collector/drain type of output. To use this you would have to create something to power the op amps and the regulator (reference source) staying under 5V. This would need probably 600 volts or more isolation from input to output. You can additional resistance in the divider chain buot expect to dissipate a lot of heat in the resistor you need to add. I would recommend you find a different sensor, this one will be dangerous to work with unless you have the experience. Consider using a voltmeter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way or not, but it works.

First of all, the circuit described above is wrong, because the battery indicator impedance(800ohm) is much smaller than resistor R2(6000ohm). so if connected in parallel like that, the resistor would be ~705.8ohm. so the voltage on the indicator will be very low (1.8V).

The correct circuit is to connect the battery indicator with a resistor in series, taking advantage of the voltage drop from the resistor.
[image]

now what to do is calculate the value of the resistor, we calculate using the voltage divider formula:

> V=Vsupply*Z/(R1+Z)
>
> 16=420*800/(R1+800)
>
> **R1= 20K ohms** (approx)

after that, what must be considered is the power dissipated is 8W. Because it's hard to find resistor above 8W, so I designed circuit consist of eight 2-watt resistors arranged as shown below

[image]